# Why do I have a high voltage drop across my full-bridge inverter output?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, ltspice

I was working on a simulation of a full bridge inverter in LTspice  which works under 15 V based on two [IR2110](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e) gate drivers and four [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) MOSFETs.

The problem is that I always get a periodic modified square wave with a very low voltage of -12 mV to 12 mV.  I changed the value of the bootstrap capacitor many times with no improvement.

Here is a screenshot of the waveform I got:

[image: wavform]

Screenshot of the circuit:

[image: circuit]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142179/discussion-on-question-by-walid-azerkane-why-do-i-have-a-high-voltage-drop-acros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulses start with HIN high, M1&M4 turned on - weird the voltage over R1 should be 12 mV, only. After 100u, LIN is high, too, all transistors are driven - don't know what to expect except a monstrous shoot through.
At 250u, HIN will turn low, shortly after, M1&M4 should turn off (unless already damaged). Voltage is complementary to 0-100u, which is good; 12 mV, which begs explanation.
At 350u, LIN will turn low, all transistors off.

Until I revisit the IR2110 datasheet to find \$V_{IL}max = 6V@15V V_{DD}\$.
\$V_{IH}min\$ is 9.5 V:

`Pulse(0 10 250u 3n 3n 249u 500u)` should set you on a more promising track.

Comment: There have been a lot of advice that, if followed, would have revealed this, including [Anton's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62807885#62807885)

Comment: is this pulse for HIN or LIN because i don't know why u delayed the signal at 250u.I think that LIN who should be delayed by 250u here is a screen of the PWM setup : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmL3m.png

Comment: I intend it for LIN, the signal you delay(ed) in the question. You'll need to set *both* pulses to more than \$V_{IH}min\$. Plot the currents to see why a width of half the period may be unwise.